# SQL syntax to join on a column alias

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation where I need to join tables on a common column name.  I have some example SQL that shows what I am trying to do.

```
declare @t table (assetid int)
declare @x table (id int)

insert into @t(assetid) values (1)
insert into @t(assetid) values (2)
insert into @t(assetid) values (3)

insert into @x(id) values (1)
insert into @x(id) values (2)
insert into @x(id) values (3)

-- SUCCESS
select assetid as assetid
from @t t 
inner join @x x on x.id = t.assetid

-- FAIL
select assetid as EntityId
from @t t 
inner join @x x on x.id = t.EntityId  <-- syntax error
```

How can I rewrite the FAIL section above where I can join not on the column name from the table, but instead on an alias of that column name?

Comment: why are you trying to do that? why not simply `select assetid as EntityId from @t t  inner join @x x on x.id = t.assetid`

Comment: Yes, that is the SUCCESS example above.  I didn't list the reason 'why'.  I just needed to know the 'how'.  I do have a valid reason for 'why'.

Comment: it is not exactly the same. there are a few different 'how', but they are not so obvious comparing to success example (without knowing 'why' at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way:

```
select EntityId
    from (select assetid as EntityId from @t) t 
    inner join @x x on x.id = t.EntityId
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use a CTE or inline view (subquery).  [`ON` is evaluated well before the `SELECT` clause.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) (Scroll to "Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement.")

It's the same reason you can't use a column alias in the `WHERE` clause, or, well, anywhere else except the `ORDER BY` clause.